# Trying to trim a video using FFMpeg in Python in a loop using variables as the start frame and end frame

Tags: python, loops, variables, ffmpeg

I'm writing a program using Python. I need to use FFMpeg as part of a loop within my program. I want FFMpeg to take my video file and create a new output each loop, using variables as the start and end point (as specific frames) How can I do this? I found some other code online which I think is on the right track but I need some help.

```
ffmpeg_start = start_sample / 29.97
ffmpeg_end = end_sample / 29.97

import os

path = '/Users/a/Downloads/Video'

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.endswith(".mp4"):
        command = "ffmpeg -fflags +discardcorrupt -i " + os.path.join(path, filename) + " -c copy -map 0 -ss {ffmpeg_start} -t {ffmpeg_end} -f segment -reset_timestamps 1 " + os.path.join(path, "output%03d.mp4")
        os.system(command)
    else:
        continue
```

The error I'm currently getting is: "Invalid duration specification for ss: {ffmpeg_start}"
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to install FFMpeg before executing this command: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html

Comment: if you have installed `ffmpeg` then you may need to use `/full/path/to/ffmpeg`

Comment: Sorry Vitor, I forgot to mention. I already have installed 'ffmpeg-python' package. Will this command only work with the standard ffmpeg package?

Comment: `ffmpeg-python` is only wrapper on C/C++ program `ffmpeg` which you have to download from https://ffmpeg.org/ and install it in system.

Comment: Furas, where would that go into the code? < path = '/Users/a/Downloads/Video/to/ffmpeg/' > ?

Comment: use direcetly `command = "/full/path/to/ffmpeg.exe  ..."`

Comment: I have both ffmpeg-python + ffmpeg installed currently.

Comment: then find full path to program `ffmpeg` (not to folder) and use this path in `command =  "/full/path/to/prorgam/ffmpeg ..."`

Comment: so you have problem with privileges. And this has nothing to do with Python but only with system. And you should search information about `developer cannot be verified` because without this privileges you can't run `ffmpeg` and you can't run your script.

Comment: Furas, that worked. Now I am getting an error, "Invalid duration specification for ss: {ffmpeg_start}"

Comment: You need to make the command string f-string